# Looping through JSON object with a conditional

Tags: python, json, dictionary, for-loop, indices

Having a bit of difficulties here with looping through this json object `content`.
The json file is as such:

```
[{'archived': False,
  'cache_ttl': None,
  'collection': {'archived': False,
   'authority_level': None,
   'color': '#509EE3',
   'description': None,
   'id': 525,
   'location': '/450/',
   'name': 'eaf',
   'namespace': None,
   'personal_owner_id': None,
   'slug': 'eaf'},
  'collection_id': 525,
  'collection_position': None,
  'created_at': '2022-01-06T20:51:17.06376Z',
  'creator_id': 1,
  'database_id': 4,
  }, ... ]
```

And I want to loop through each dict in the list check that the collection is not empty and then for each collection if the location equals `'/450/'` return append that dict to a list.

My code is as follows.

```
content = json.loads(res.text)
```

```
for q in content:
  if q['collection']:
    for col in q['collection']:
      if col['location'] == '/450/':
        data.append(q)
  
print(data)
```

Having played around with it I keep either getting `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` OR   `TypeError: string indices must be integers`
Any help with my structure would be much appreciated thanks.

Disclaimer:
I had previously written this as a list comprehension and it worked like a charm however that doesnt work anymore as I now need to check if the `collection` is empty.
How I wrote it previously:

```
content = [ x for x in content if x['collection']['location'] == '/450/']
```

Comment: You're getting `TypeError: string indices must be integers` because `col` is a string, and you're trying to do `col['location']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work for you:

```
for q in content:
    if q['collection']['location'] == '/450/':
        data.append(q)
  
print(data)
```

If you go with `for` loop with `for col in q['collection']`, you just iterate over keys inside `q['collection']`, so `cols = ['archived', 'authority_level', ...]`.

Answer (score 1):

From your previous list comprehension, `"location"` is a key in `q["collection"]`.
When you write

```
for col in q["collection"]
```

You are iterating over the keys in `q["collection"]`. One of these keys is `"location"`. Your for loop seems to iterate more than necessary:

```
if q['collection'] and "location" in q["collection"] and q["collection"]["location"]  == "/450/":
    data.append(q)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need to iterate over the *collection* object since it's a dictionary and just need to check the location property.

Also, in case the "collection" or "location" properties are not present then use dict.get(key) function rather than dict[key] since the latter will raise a KeyError exception if key is not found and get() returns *None* value if key is not found.

```python
content = [{'archived': False,
        'cache_ttl': None,
        'collection': {'archived': False,
                       'authority_level': None,
                       'color': '#509EE3',
                       'description': None,
                       'id': 525,
                       'location': '/450/',
                       'name': 'eaf',
                       'namespace': None,
                       'personal_owner_id': None,
                       'slug': 'eaf'},
        'collection_id': 525,
        'collection_position': None,
        'created_at': '2022-01-06T20:51:17.06376Z',
        'creator_id': 1,
        'database_id': 4,
        },
       {'foo': None}
       ]

#content = json.loads(res.text)
data = []
for q in content:
    c = q.get('collection')
    if c and c.get('location') == '/450/':
        data.append(q)
  
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'archived': False, 'cache_ttl': None, 'collection': { 'location': '/450/', 'name': 'eaf', 'namespace': None }, ...}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ***Code Has Way too Iterations*** Than needed.

The error `TypeError: string indices must be integers` occurs at the s*econd conditional statement* when you check **col['location'] = "/450/"**.

That's because not all **tokens** in the **collection object** have **sub-objects** where you can ***get data with their key***.

Take a look at your ***old code*** and the ***modified code*** for more in depth understanding.

```py
# Your old json datas
content  = [{'archived': False,
  'cache_ttl': None,
  'collection': {'archived': False,
   'authority_level': None,
   'color': '#509EE3',
   'description': None,
   'id': 525,
   'location': '/450/',
   'name': 'eaf',
   'namespace': None,
   'personal_owner_id': None,
   'slug': 'eaf'},
  'collection_id': 525,
  'collection_position': None,
  'created_at': '2022-01-06T20:51:17.06376Z',
  'creator_id': 1,
  'database_id': 4,
  } ]

data = []
for q in content:
    if q['collection']:
        for col in q['collection']: 
            if col['location'] == '/450/': # The first object in collection object is [archived] which is a string, this causes the program to throw error
                data.append(q)
  
print(data)
```

Here is the modified code

```py
# Your json datas
json_datas = [{'archived': False,
  'cache_ttl': None,
  'collection': {'archived': False,
   'authority_level': None,
   'color': '#509EE3',
   'description': None,
   'id': 525,
   'location': '/450/',
   'name': 'eaf',
   'namespace': None,
   'personal_owner_id': None,
   'slug': 'eaf'},
  'collection_id': 525,
  'collection_position': None,
  'created_at': '2022-01-06T20:51:17.06376Z',
  'creator_id': 1,
  'database_id': 4,
  } ]


list_data = [] # Your list data in which appends the json data if the location is /450/

for data in json_datas: # Getting each Json data
  if len(data["collection"]): # Continue if the length of collection is not 0 [NOTE: 0 = False, 1 or more = True]
    if data['collection']['location'] == "/450/": # Check the location
      list_data.append(data) # Append if true


print(list_data)
```