# How to Filter JSON Files in Jinja Template?

Tags: json, jinja2

I have some JSON files that look like:

```
{
   "id":"_n2tEUURGiY",
   "title":"I Just",
   "formats":[
      {
         "format_id":"sb2",
         "format_note":"storyboard",
         "ext":"mhtml",
         "protocol":"mhtml",
         "acodec":"none",
         "vcodec":"none",
         "url":"",
         "width":48,
         "height":27,
         "fps":0.45871559633027525,
         "rows":10,
         "columns":10,
         "fragments":[
            {
               "url":"",
               "duration":218.0
            }
         ],
         "audio_ext":"none",
         "video_ext":"none",
         "format":"sb2 - 48x27 (storyboard)",
},
      {
         "format_id":"sb1",
         "format_note":"storyboard",
         "ext":"mhtml",
         "protocol":"mhtml",
         "acodec":"none",
         "vcodec":"none",
         "url":"",
         "width":45,
         "height":45,
         "fps":0.5091743119266054,
         "rows":10,
         "columns":10,
         "fragments":[
            {
               "url":"",
               "duration":196.39639639639637
            },
            {
               "url":"",
               "duration":21.60360360360363
            }
         ],
         "audio_ext":"none",
         "video_ext":"none",
         "format":"sb1 - 45x45 (storyboard)",
         "resolution":"45x45",
         "http_headers":{
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4556.0 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode":"navigate"
         }
      },
{
         "asr":48000,
         "filesize":3772787,
         "format_id":"251",
         "format_note":"medium",
         "source_preference":-1,
         "fps":"None",
         "audio_channels":2,
         "height":"None",
         "quality":3,
         "has_drm":false,
         "tbr":138.348,
         "url":"",
         "width":"None",
         "language":"",
         "language_preference":-1,
         "preference":"None",
         "ext":"webm",
         "vcodec":"none",
         "acodec":"opus",
         "dynamic_range":"None",
         "abr":138.348,
         "downloader_options":{
            "http_chunk_size":10485760
         },
         "container":"webm_dash",
         "protocol":"https",
         "audio_ext":"webm",
         "video_ext":"none",
         "format":"251 - audio only (medium)",
         "resolution":"audio only",
         "http_headers":{
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4556.0 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode":"navigate"
         }
      },
{
         "asr":44100,
         "filesize":"None",
         "format_id":"18",
         "format_note":"360p",
         "source_preference":-1,
         "fps":25,
         "audio_channels":2,
         "height":360,
         "quality":6,
         "has_drm":false,
         "tbr":172.717,
         "url":",
         "width":360,
         "language":"",
         "language_preference":-1,
         "preference":"None",
         "ext":"mp4",
         "vcodec":"avc1.42001E",
         "acodec":"mp4a.40.2",
         "dynamic_range":"SDR",
         "protocol":"https",
         "video_ext":"mp4",
         "audio_ext":"none",
         "vbr":172.717,
         "abr":0.0,
         "format":"18 - 360x360 (360p)",
         "resolution":"360x360",
         "filesize_approx":4819495,
         "http_headers":{
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4556.0 Safari/537.36",
            "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
            "Accept-Language":"en-us,en;q=0.5",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode":"navigate"
         }
      },
```

I made a Jinja template like:

```
{% for format in formats %}   
                        
         {{format.format_name}}                          
                        
                    
 {% endfor %}
```

This makes it show all of the `format`s. How can i filter the output, so that it only shows formats where `'format_id'` is either `"sb2"` or `"sb1"`?

Comment: There seems to be quite a bit of important code that you are not showing us in between JSON response and Jinja template. Please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As for not being able to say "Hi" - you are not supposed to. Greetings and other pleasantries are unecessary and detract attention from the actual question - [Do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)

Comment: you put "python" in the tags, yet I see no python code here. Is there a python component you haven't shown us?
if you're iterating through the json object in python, this SO question might help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70839658/looping-through-json-object-with-a-conditional

Comment: oh, i am sorry. and sorry too that i am supposed to give jinja in the tags. i revise it. thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "EDIT : how come i cannot say HI at the top of this thread? it always remove automatically" Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950. Keep in mind that Stack Overflow is **not a discussion forum**, and your question is not a "thread". We do not want you to write things like "Hi", "thanks" or anything else like that. We want you to ask the question directly, with as little else as possible. We want the problem to be explained as clearly as possible. I [edit]ed the post to show how it should look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of your for loop you can use an if statment [jinja if](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#if)

```
{% for format in formats %}   
  {% if format.format_id in ["sb1", "sb2"] %}
         {{format.format_name}}                          
  {% endif %}                    
{% endfor %}
```

PS: In your JSON data, the format objects do not have a "format_name" key.

Comment: ahh, okay. let me try it first.

EDIT : nice! i though it gonna be complex code. but it works though. thanks!